# How to terminate a process(httpd) when its PID keeps on changing in CENTOS 7

Tags: httpd, centos7, ps

When I tried to restart my httpd service using `systemctl restart httpd`

Checking the status, I found that process is dead and another process is running. so I removed it using `yum erase httpd`

As a precaution, I checked if the process is still running using  `ps aux | grep httpd#` and found it was but this time the PID was different. and after subsequent queries, the PID kept on changing. If I try to kill using any PID, it would say `NO Such Process`

Check the screenshot:

[image]

Hence the question. How do I stop this process so that I can install the service from scratch and configure it?

Comment: This PID isn't http process. This PID is grep proccess. Try "systemctl status httpd" for check httpd status. But if you erase httpd package, you haven't any process of httpd

Comment: Exactly my question. When i have already erased the httpd package, how am I getting httpd (pid 22595) already running .

Comment: You also grep for `httpd#` including the `#`. Remove the `#` to actually properly match for httpd.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to understand that when you `grep httpd` you'll not just get back any apache processes **but the grep process as well**. You're seeing your own command reflected back at you.

> # ps ax | grep httpd
>    1818 ?        Ss     0:53 /usr/sbin/httpd
>   38729 ?        S      4:38 /usr/sbin/httpd
>   38730 ?        S      4:49 /usr/sbin/httpd
>   **54915 pts/0    S+     0:00 grep httpd**

Comment: Unserstood. But still if I try systemctl status httpd , I get the same error as  httpd (pid 22595) already running and  Failed to start The Apache HTTP Server.

Comment: Try this instead `service httpd status`

Comment: Same Error. Also when I try to kill 22595, it says NO such process

Comment: My best guess then is that the [httpd.pid file](http://superuser.com/questions/422850/why-does-apache-write-its-own-process-id-in-httpd-pid) still exists and the system is returning that. Since your `grep` is empty you might want to make sure that file was deleted

Comment: Can't really find file anywhere. can you please tell me its possible location apart from var/run?

Comment: Mine lives at `/var/run/httpd/httpd.pid`

Comment: Hmmm, no such folder as httpd in run. So could it be any other error?

Comment: Beyond rebooting I don't have any other suggestions

Comment: hmmm, tried everything, but ultimately had to reboot. now its working fine

Answer (score 2):

Try:
    `find / -name "httpd.pid"`

Then delete the pid file, if it exists.


Also, just in case:
    `systemctl stop httpd`
    `systemctl disable httpd`

Machavity is right too, whenever you grep from the output of ps you're going to see your grep command too. It's something you'll get used to.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is you could do `killall httpd` as a way to kill all processes named httpd.

Comment: Tried that but didn't work. @Machavity 's suggestion of restart worked.